# Developing ExactTarget app in JAVA SDK: Part 2

Tags: marketing-cloud, java, fuel-sdk

The example for updating Data Extensions in "[Developing ExactTarget app in JAVA SDK](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34088/developing-exact-target-app-in-java-sdk)" was what I have been looking for. Unfortunately, I'm not able to get it work for Shared Data Extensions.

I've tried using the `ENT.` prefix on the name with no luck. I've tried including the folder name beneath the Shared Data Extension folder in the name (Like `ENT.subfoldername.deName`) with no luck.

Is there a trick I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Any API solution needs to use the Customer Key field to reference a data extension external to the APP, not the name.  Try looking that up, plug that in, and see if that works.

Comment: OK, so in our case, it turns out this was set to be the same as the name. I'm basing that on the contents of the External Key field on the web interface to the data extension.

Comment: Is the API user an admin across all business units?

Comment: Yes. I created the app in app center using my account and I am an admin

Answer (score 0):

Your API user will have a default Business Unit that is used when you log-in and when you're accessing the account via the API.

If you are trying to access the Shared Data Extensions on the account and are only seeing the BU's data extensions, you would want to be sure you're referencing the Parent Level MID as the Client ID in  your code.  That will ensure we know where to look for the Data Extension's External Key and you can successfully update as needed.

Let me know how that works out.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, what you are saying makes sense, but what do you mean by Parent Level MID. Newbie to ExactTarget here.

Comment: Shared Data Extensions are a part of an Enterprise 2.0 account.  There would be a main (parent) top level account where all other Business Units were created.  It sounds like you most likely have your user defaulting to a Business Unit so you would need to reference that Account Number (MID) for the Parent Level Account, as that is where Shared DE's are stored.  Let me know if that helps and see below for some info on ENT2.0 accounts http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/enterprise/enterprise_20_overview/

Comment: Thanks, I've come to realize that I don't need the data extensions to be shared, so I've gotten past this.