# Retrieve rows from a Synchronized DE through SOAP API using Access Token from REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm trying to retrieve rows from a Synchronized DE using the SOAP API with the REST API Access Token:

I've seen this: [Cannot retrieve fields from a Shared Data Extension using the SOAP API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132602/cannot-retrieve-fields-from-a-shared-data-extension-using-the-soap-api)

And this: http://www.kellyjandrews.com/2014/02/20/using-fuel-oauth-with-the-soap-api.html

I am able to retrieve a Data Extension Object and Folders, but no rows from a DE.

Here's my request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{Access Token}}</fueloauth>
  </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[Contact_Salesforce]</ObjectType>
            <Properties>Email</Properties>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I get this error:
**Error: API Permission Failed.**

I'm wondering if it could have something to do with the Package/API Integration that was set-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird. In the API Integration permission settings, I had to set Read and **Write** Permissions for Data Extensions in order to do a Retrieve on a Data Extension.

Comment: OMG WOW.  Thank you for saving me a lot of time.