# Developing java integration with Fuel SDK

Tags: java, fuel-sdk

I am starting to develop the connection between my system and the one from Exact Target, but having some troubles.

I tried to follow this example, but many functions do not work anymore or are deprecated.

[Developing ExactTarget app in JAVA SDK](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34088/developing-exact-target-app-in-java-sdk/34170#34170)

Can someone provide an updated example on how to insert a new row to a data extension?

Thank you
Cheers,
Luiz

Comment: How far did you get in your quest?

Answer (score 1):

Below is example of insert new row in DataExtension name "Cocoa"
This code is Scala but it's look similar to Java.

```
val response = client.retrieve(classOf[ETDataExtension], "name = Cocoa")
val de = response.getResult().getObject

val row = new ETDataExtensionRow()
row.setColumn("ID", "1")
row.setColumn("Name", "Coco Nobody0")
row.setColumn("Email", "nb0@agoda.com")

val res = de.insert(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will insert new row in DE named 'MyDataExtension' (Subscribers --> Data Extensions). First we filter by the external key. Then we insert the data.

```
ETFilter etFilter = new ETFilter();
etFilter.setClient(client);
ETExpression etExpression = new ETExpression();
etExpression.setProperty("CustomerKey");
etExpression.setValue("MyDataExtension");
etExpression.setOperator(Operator.EQUALS);
etFilter.setExpression(etExpression);

ETResponse<ETDataExtension> dataExtension = client.retrieve(ETDataExtension.class,etFilter);
for (ETDataExtension etDataExtension : dataExtension.getObjects()) {
          System.out.println(
                " ID:" + etDataExtension.getId() +
                " Key:" + etDataExtension.getKey() +
                " Name:" + etDataExtension.getName()+
                " Description:" + etDataExtension.getDescription() +
                " Create Date:" + etDataExtension.getCreatedDate()+
                " Modified Date:" + etDataExtension.getModifiedDate());
            }
ETDataExtensionRow row = new ETDataExtensionRow();
row.setColumn("Firstname", "XXXXXX");
row.setColumn("EmailAddress", "XXXX@YYYY.com");
ETResponse<ETDataExtensionRow> response = dataExtension.getObjects().get(0).insert(row);
```